# install Tizen studio 3.7 on Ubuntu 19.10 or 20.04?

Tags: linux, tizen

I am stuck on this warning while installing Tizen studio via package manager as it requires a preriquisite:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

running this command finds nothing. Following askubuntu forum I downloaded bunch of `webkitgtk` packages from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkitgtk). Finally I got this error that demonstrates it requires more dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg -i '/home/rif/Downloads/w/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb'
```

error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 156927 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 (2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (= 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) | libegl1-x11; however:

        ...and more stuff not installed, message...

Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64
```

I have no idea what I should do to install this on Linux. How can I install it Tizen studio on Linux 20.04?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 on Ubuntu 19/20 for now is listed below

1. `echo -e "# For Tizen studio\ndeb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tizen-bionic-libwebkitgtk.list`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`

And once the libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is installed the user might face difficulty in installing libpng12 as well when trying to install any emulators.

Steps to install libpng12 are below

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install libpng12-0`

After installing the libpng12 & libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 packages, user will be able to install any profile in Ubuntu 19 or Ubuntu 20.

Tizen Studio does not officially support Ubuntu 19 & Ubuntu 20 as of now.
Official support for Ubuntu 20 LTS is expected soon

Answer (score 0):

There is no libwebkitgtk-1.0 for Ubuntu 19.10 or 20.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

If you want libwebkitgtk-1.0 in Ubuntu 19.10/20.04, you will need to download its source code and try to build (probably with debuild) or install Ubuntu 18.04 in a docker.

Other Tizen tools are not yet officially supported in 19.10 or 20.04.
Or you may contact admins and ask them to add another Ubuntu version support at https://launchpad.net/~tizen.org/+archive/ubuntu/pdk

Comment: Can you please write more details on "If you want libwebkitgtk-1.0 in Ubuntu 19.10/20.04, you will need to download its source code and try to build (probably with debuild)"? Getting libwebkitgtk-1.0 in Ubuntu 19.10/20.04 is main focus here.

Comment: For example, visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 and get source code from there. Then, build it in a Ubuntu 20.04.machine.

It is not being maintained by recent Ubuntu versions anymore, so as long as there are no volunteers to maintain it in PPA, you need to build it on your own. (or, downgrade Ubuntu or install an older Ubuntu w/ docker)

Comment: Why I need to build it from source, when it has compiled binaries for different platforms on my linked url?  Also libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 doesn't need to be maintained anymore as new versions were introduced. Also I know it runs on Ubuntu 18.4.

Comment: If you can ensure that libwebkitgtk-1.0 binary (from another platform or versions) uses the exactly same headers of system libraries and no additional dependencies, you are safe to go. If you believe so, you can install libwebkitgtk-1.0 from 18.04 in 20.04 machines with dpkg.